# Getting network utilization using wmi in c#

Tags: c#, math, network-programming, wmi

I am trying to get a percentage value for network utilization based on per adapter

I've tried this:

```
CurrentBandwidth = 1000000000;
BytesTotalPerSec = 34610;
var bytesTotal = (BytesTotalPerSec * 8);
var utilizationPerc = (CurrentBandwidth / bytesTotal) / 100;
```

This is not giving me the correct value, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: what are your results, what are the expected results?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured out the issue, I had to explicitly declare a double:

```
var output2 = (double)BytesTotalPerSec / TotalBW;
```